# how do i show a different page in vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, components

i have this problem with my code. I need to show a "thank you" page when succesfully submitted the information on my form. if form is valid it should take the user to a "thank you page". i know that this can be done without using router. i just need to show this page whenever i click the submit button and everything is filled ok. Can someone please help me with this?.

This is my code

The component im trying to show

> import SendForm from './components/SendForm.vue';

```
const send = (e) => {
  const isFormValid = validate()
  console.log(isFormValid)

  if(isFormValid) { 
    fetch('URL', {
      method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: formData
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Using v-if and reactive variables you could display components (SendForm.vue), when you validate the form in the main component

Comment: @BenjaJorquera try it, but it doesn’t work :(

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a technical description of a problem.  Show the code from your attempt, even if it's not correct.  Explain what doesn't work actually means.  If you want detailed answers you must provide detailed questions.

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/GQoY22L.gif](https://i.imgur.com/GQoY22L.gif)